# JSON Openload PHP

Tags: php, json

Alguém pode me ajudar? tenho a seguinte url json: https://api.openload.co/1/file/info?file=6PHaY9bqRYc

Queria saber como fazer pra listar em php cada parte que tem na json deixando tipo

Nome: nome que tem na json
Id: id que tem na json

E para um json assim:

```
{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"ticket":"valorticket","captcha_url":"valorcaptcha","captcha_w":160,"captcha_h":70,"wait_time":0,"valid_until":"2018-05-11 15:55:44"}}
```

Como ficaria o código? tenho uma url com o json desde jeito, tentei alterando a url e não da resultado, somente erros

Answer (score 3):

Usando `curl` ou `file_get_contents` e depois usando `json_decode`.

O resultado disto:

```
{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"6PHaY9bqRYc":{"id":"6PHaY9bqRYc","status":200,"name":"big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4","size":"1055726","sha1":"5b4395dabecd6308ec82bb4f1626f41c40e64654","content_type":"video\/mp4","cstatus":"1"}}}
```

Com `json_decode` vai ser mais ou menos estes:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 200
    [msg] => OK
    [result] => Array
        (
            [6PHaY9bqRYc] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6PHaY9bqRYc
                    [status] => 200
                    [name] => big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4
                    [size] => 1055726
                    [sha1] => 5b4395dabecd6308ec82bb4f1626f41c40e64654
                    [content_type] => video/mp4
                    [cstatus] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Então terá que usar um `foreach` também, exemplo:

```
<?php

$response = file_get_contents('https://api.openload.co/1/file/info?file=6PHaY9bqRYc');

if (!$response) {
   die('Erro nos dados');
}

$data = json_decode($response, true);

if ($data['status'] != 200) {
   die('Erro HTTP:' . $data['status']);
}

foreach ($data['result'] as $id => $details) {
    echo 'id: ', $details['id'], '<br>';
    echo 'Nome: ', $details['name'], '<br>';
    echo 'Tamanho: ', $details['size'], '<br>';
    echo 'Content-Type: ', $details['content_type'], '<hr>';
}
```

---

Do outro JSON:

```
{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"ticket":"valorticket","captcha_url":"valorcaptcha","captcha_w":160,"captcha_h":70,"wait_time":0,"valid_until":"2018-05-11 15:55:44"}}
```

deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

//Esta em string, mas suponho que venha de uma URL
$response = '{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"ticket":"valorticket","captcha_url":"valorcaptcha","captcha_w":160,"captcha_h":70,"wait_time":0,"valid_until":"2018-05-11 15:55:44"}}';

if (!$response) {
   die('Erro nos dados');
}

$data = json_decode($response, true);

if ($data['status'] != 200) {
   die('Erro HTTP:' . $data['status']);
}

$result = $data['result'];

print_r($result);

echo 'ticket: ', $result['ticket'], PHP_EOL;
echo 'URL captcha: ', $result['captcha_url'], PHP_EOL;
echo 'Largura captcha: ', $result['captcha_w'], PHP_EOL;
echo 'Largura altura: ', $result['captcha_h'], PHP_EOL;
echo 'Validade: ', $result['valid_until'], PHP_EOL;
```

Não precisa de `foreach` porque o `result` só recebe "um objeto", já o outro json recebia no `result:` um objeto com chave variante, por exemplo `"6PHaY9bqRYc":` e ainda era "multi-dimensional".

Comment: Pode me ajudar com o json no formato que está agora? tentei e só da erro

Comment: @RogérioSilva que erro? Seja sempre especifico por favor, isso ajuda a entender os problemas para que eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: Illegal string offset 'ticket'

Comment: @RogérioSilva editei a resposta, veja o exemplo para o segundo JSON e leia a explicação.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `file_get_contens()` e `json_decode`:

```
<?php
    $json=file_get_contents('https://api.openload.co/1/file/info?file=6PHaY9bqRYc');
    $json=json_decode($json);
    echo 'Status: '.$json->status;
?>
```

> [Referência da função **file_get_contents()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)
>
> [Referência da função **json_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)